# "Wow! It's already the end of April" "Yeah, you're right. Time ...": Time flies and whatelse?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, difference, sentence-usage

I was wondering about the difference between these sentences. They all translate the German "Der Zeit vergeht so schnell" or the Italian "il tempo vola". 
I would like to know if:

- all of them are correct;
- there is any significant geographical difference between them. If for instance one is more used in the US and another somewhere else, in case please specify where.
- I'd also like to know which one is the most likely to be used in a colloquial situation, maybe as one is speaking with a friend and realizes "Wow! It's already the end of April" "Yeah, time ... (whatever expression).  a native speaker would use).

  1. Time flies!
  2. Time goes by so fast/quickly!
  3. Time passes so fast/quickly

Is there any other way to express this? In case let me please know! 
Thank you all, 
Eli

Answer (score 1):

Time flies!

Time goes by so fast/quickly!

Time passes so fast/quickly!

These three sentences are correct and there is no difference between them.

But, mostly *time flies* is used in a colloquial language and it's more common expression.

Answer (score 0):

Latin would be "tempus fugit."

"[Something happened] in the blink of an eye."

"[Something happened] in a New York minute."  That would be very fast indeed!  Somehow a "NY minute" is faster than a minute anywhere else on Earth.

"Lightning" might also be used to express something happening very quickly, like the Blitzkrieg.  "That horse was fast as lightning!"